# How to use same template on different components in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Currently I am using as

```
<template> ... </template>
<script src="test1.js"> </script>
```

Where all my business logics are written in test1.js. Now I need to use test2.js with same template. I need to reuse the template with different component.

My current code goes like this...

common.vue

```
<template>
 <div>
   {{ page }}
 </div>
<template>

<script src="../scripts/test1.js"></script>
```

Where in test1.js

```
export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: {
    test: test
  },
  data() {
    return {
        page: "test1",
    }
  }
}
```

But also i need to use common.vue in my test2.js. Which i am not able to import both the .js seperately.

In angular we can write the fallowing late bindig which binds .html and .js(in ui.router)

```
    .state('home', {
        url:'/',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })
```

Is there something similar to this?

Comment: Share any live demo of this ?

Comment: @user2486, hope now it explains more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

You can share the template through the `id` attribute.

```js
Vue.component('my-comp1', {
  template: '#generic',
  data () {
    return {
      text: 'I am component 1'
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('my-comp2', {
  template: '#generic',
  data () {
    return {
      text: 'I am component 2'
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <my-comp1></my-comp1>
  <my-comp2></my-comp2>
</div>

<template id="generic">
  <div>
    <p>{{ text }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

Comment: Would like to highlight that separating a template from a component definition should generally be avoided. This is due to the tight coupling required between a component inheriting a template and the template itself as the output of the component is dependent on the interface of the template. See the [guide on x-templates](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#X-Templates) for Vue's own warning regarding this pattern. A mechanism for re-use is already provided through [components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) and should be favoured over x-templates.

Comment: I do not use templates in this way, nor do I recommend using them this way.

Comment: @WaldemarIce Then how to reuse the templates which needs different functionalities? Is there any other way to do that??

Comment: Yes, i is. You can use slots, especially scoped slots, or you can use something like <component :is='anyComponents'>.